# Overloading the new and delete operator globally

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I was trying to overload the new and delete operator globally.
The code is:

```
void * operator new(size_t s)
    {
        cout<<"\nOverloaded new operator with size "<<s<<endl;
        void * ptr=::malloc(s);
        return  ptr;
    }
    void operator delete(void * ptr)
    {
        cout<<"\nOverloaded delete operator\n";
        free(ptr);
    }
class Array
{
    int * arr;
    int n;
public:

    Array(int x=0):n{x}
    {
        cout<<"\nConstructor called\n";
        arr= new int[n];
    }

    ~Array()
    {
        cout<<"\nDestructor called\n";
        delete[]arr;
    }
    void set_data()
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter elements:";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }

    }
    void show_data()
    {
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }


};
int main()
{
    Array * a=new Array{3};
    a->set_data();
    a->show_data();
    delete a;


    return 0;

}
```

When I tried creating an Array object using new, the output of set_data() function was something that confused me. It seems to me as if every time an array element is taken as input, an object is created on heap and deleted immediately.
Please explain this behavior
Output

[image: Output for Array of three elements]

Also I am doing this concept for the first time. So if I am mistaken in understanding the concept please help me

Comment: Not casting a void pointer explicitly, I am sure that generates a warning in C++ (though its recommended in C)

Comment: the code does not compile! There's the header file stuff missing.

Comment: Also, what did the debugger [say](https://imgur.com/a/Gpy8Krc)?

Comment: `s` is undefined at the first call

Comment: Just a caution: using C++library components (`std::cout << "whatever";`) in a replacement `operator new` can cause problems. There is no guarantee that operations on those components don't themselves use `new`; if that happens the code will die a recursive death. It's safer to use C-style output (i.e., `printf`).

Comment: As a matter of terminology, this is not **overloading** those operators. It's **replacing** them.